# Cygwin portable?

Tags: portable, cygwin

### Question:

- Is it possible, to have a functional **minimalistic** (or default) setup of [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on a portable medium, such as a USB stick? If so, **how** can this be achieved?

  - What would be the most suitable file system, to use accordingly?

Comment: FAT32 - possibly

Comment: with fat32 you WILL have issues because ACL is not supported. eg. tmux dosn't work with default session unless /tmp supports ACL. Because of ACL I'd go with NTFS even when it's not the best system for USBs..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [**site**](http://sites.google.com/site/devinsezer/Home/software/portable-cygwin) **explains** how to install onto a USB stick.

Comment: The referenced answer is broken because of a broken link. It would have been better, if you had written a real answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are quite a few options here, I started with [Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com/). It's very user-friendly and easy to use. One critical down-side however, is that it's virtualization has issues with some programs and doesn't always work well, if at all for said programs. After Cameyo, I made the jump to [VMWare ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp.html). A bit more complex, but you can achieve much more with this tool. If you use it it will take some getting used to, as editing a project after a capture requires you to *manually* edit the project's Package.ini, as well as other assets without the aide of a GUI. And finally, there's [Turbo Studio](https://turbo.net/studio) (Formerly Spoon Studio). This one is a bit pricy as it is now subscription based, and is about half-way between Cameyo and ThinApp. It has the user-interface and integration of cameyo, stacked with the complexity and diversity of ThinApp. And as others have stated, [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/), but I haven't used it and therefore have no opinion on it. I would recommend capturing your post-snapshot with your preferred virtualizer and set it up with the settings you want as it's defaults. I would also use either NTFS or exFAT for the filesystem. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Alas, not that great of an answer, I've spent some time trying, and not really gotten anything I'm happy with, I use portableapps.com for almost everything at work, but not for getting Unix, or even emacs.

Not to say that this is not a solvable problem or even a hard one, I think someone who groks windows just needs to take a look at it.

File system wise, depends where you want to uses it. Probably ntfs, if all you care about is windows (well, can work with Linux), I use fat32 on a 4gb (wasteful for cygwin though, many small files), and I've looked at using UDF (DVD file system), but need to get around to making my linux box write to it.